# Counting occurrences of a special character via hex address (file validation purposes)

Tags: c#, arrays, hex, byte

My issue is I need to validate .txt files prior to processing. Each .txt file has a trailer record with the number of rows it has. I made some progress and simplified the code I was working on for my question, but I'm getting an inaccurate count for certain files by a considerable amount(30+), while others work fine. I'm counting occurrences of a special character which registers as "40" in decimal, and "0x28" in hex by reading the files in byte by byte. Any help is appreciated Here's my code:

***UPDATE*** Thanks to all who commented. Here is a sample of the .txt(trailer record count is at the end, followed by the box(0x28)):

> "T"|"2017-02-28 03:00:05:043"|"147

```
string filepath = @"some file path";
int recordCount = 0;
byte[] dataArray = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.Length; i++)
{

    if (dataArray[i] == 0x28)
    {
        recordCount++;

    }
 }



 Console.WriteLine("Record count: " + recordCount);
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: 0x28 is not a special character,it's just a `(`. I guess you'll need to give us a sample input file and the expected result

Comment: Please provide sample input that demonstrates the problem. So far code matches your requirement. E.g. input: `"(\"Bob (the builder)\",42)`, expected output = 1.

Comment: First of all, 0x28 is not a special character, it's '(' as noted above. Also, what is the encoding of a file you work with? If the file, for example, is UTF16LE, then your code probably is not working as you expect it to work.

Comment: Side note: LINQ version would be more appropriate as part of [MCVE] as it is much shorter - `recordCount = dataArray.Count(b => b == '(');`

Comment: Apologies, I used a linq version of my code before but wasn't sure if that was giving me issues so I went a different route. I sued the term special character because it came up as a box when I open the .txt file.

Comment: If you are refering to the first character in the sample string, the code for it (at least in UTF-8) is  0xEF. Try to search for that.